# Crashes when using gnome tweak tool with Gnome 3.4

Tags: gnome

Well i'm new in this site and i have some problems with Ubuntu 12.04

I made a clean installation and install gnome 3.4, gnome classic and cinnamon
but when i want to run gnome tweak tool in gnome 3.4, it closes immediately, in Unity, Cinnamon and gnome classic it runs perfectly.

Also I always receive a warning about Ubuntu crashed and sometimes it reboots
Can you help me in this?

Comment: run gnome tweak tool from terminal and post the output here

Comment: well i saw what's the problem, i have installed the gnome extension "user theme" and it prevented to run the program, after i unistalled it, gnome tweak tool runs in gnome 3.4, but about the crashes in ubuntu 12.04, is it unstable yet?

Comment: ok, i'll see it, it can be, well thanks for helping me

Answer (score 18):

If you try running it from an terminal and you get this error:

```
(gnome-tweak-tool:4506): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Then you can run the following two commands from a terminal to add the schema to the system:

```
sudo cp $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

To run gnome-tweak-tool from the command line start Terminal and just type:

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

And press enter

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. I'll update the answer with the complete error message so it's easier to find via Google et al.

Comment: while doing your suggested command i get this error No such file or directory. 
Becuase before coming to this thread I read on some other ubuntu forum that i should to delete .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions.

Comment: @Abhijit Have you tried going to http://extensions.gnome.org/ and reinstalling your extensions?

Comment: @Agentk Yes I tried reinstall it 2-3 times. What I found out was that, If I had this extension uninstalled then tweak tool runs fine. The moment I install it, the tweak tool again refuses to run.

Comment: @AbhijitNavale Excellent. Exactly what I was experiencing too until I ran the sudo cp command above.